# Lyx: How to add option to package automatically load

Tags: packages, lyx, urls, package-options

I got the problem, that links in `\url` only break in LyX when there is a `\` character in it. I found the solution to add `\usepackage[hyphens]{url}` to my preamble.

But the problem is, LyX loads the package `url` with no options, and I get an error. How can I solve this?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) I believe you can somehow modify the document preamble in LyX (I've never used it so I don't know the details). You can add the line `\PassOptionsToPackage{hyphens}{url}` before `\documentclass` and you should be fine :)

Comment: I tried, doesn't seem to work... Perhaps my solution isn't right.

Comment: @tohecz I don't think you can add anything before `\documentclass` in LyX. You can add options to the document class however, which will also pass it to all packages (right?).

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Jees, all options to class are passed to all packages as well, as long as the packages are loaded after the class.

Comment: THANKS! I just inserted `hyphens` in the options and it worked!

Comment: But now i got the problem, that Links are just clickable in the first line, and the browser opens the wrong page -.-

Comment: Can you illustrate your problem via an example? Adding a screenshot  of your LyX editor interface (or a link to the screenshot) would help. Also, when I add `\usepackage[hyphens]{url}` in the LaTeX Preamble in LyX, the option is loaded correctly.

Comment: Solved! I forgot using `\usepackage{hyperref}` and I loaded the old package `subfigure` instead of `subfig`. Now everything works fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A workaround for this problem would be to add `hyphens` to the document class options, in Document --> Settings --> Document class. Any options added to the document class will also be applied to all packages loaded later.

Answer (score 3):

According to [this answer](https://www.mail-archive.com/lyx-users@lists.lyx.org/msg102234.html), LyX 2.2 now supports putting into **Document > Settings > Local Layout**:

```
PackageOptions url hyphens
```

I have successfully used this with todonotes, but haven't tried it with your specific problem.