# How do I prevent LyX from loading fontspec automatically?

Tags: lyx, lyx-layouts

I would like to use non-TeX fonts in LyX. To do this, I use the **Document->Setting->Use non-TeX fonts** setting. This setting causes LyX to insert the `\usepackage{fontspec}` statement automatically into the preamble. However, I would like to load the **fontspec** with specific options. I have tried to do `\usepackage[LY1,T1]{fontspec}` for example. Even with this LyX still does `\usepackage{fontspec}` and I end up with two statements which both load `fontspec` in the preamble. I have tried using the command `Provides fontspec 1` in the layout file in the hope that LyX would not load `fontspec` automatically. It still does. What is interesting is that LyX does the automatic package loading on a line that precedes the one on which I ask it to load `fontspec` with specified options.

Does somebody have an idea of how I could condition LyX to let me load `fontspec` with the required options without it loading `fontspec` automatically?

Comment: `fontspec` is a xelatex and lualatex specific package that does not work with latex or pdflatex and does not take options such as `LY1` or `T1` are you thinking of `fontenc` (which does take those options) ?

Comment: Thanks David for pointing out my confusion between fonspec and fontenc. I pledge my ignorance: I started using the two packages last week. I have mixed them up. How embarassing? But how could one manage to tell LyX not load a package if one wants to load that package with a specific set of options? Thanks, in advance.

Comment: David's comment notwithstanding, the way to do this (with options corresponding to the package, of course) is with `\PassOptionsToPackage{<options>}{<package>}` _before_ the package is loaded. This may be possible in LyX using "ERT"; just a matter of making sure this code comes before LyX loads the package in question.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response Paul. Your suggestion is certainly a good avenue for me to explore and I think it should work. However, I have one problem, by the time we use "ERT" are we not past the \begin{document} line already (and not in the preamble)?

Comment: @user24098 sorry I have never seen lyx

Comment: Off-topic: if you want to use non-TeX fonts, you almost certainly do want to load `fontspec` and not to load `fontenc`. You can use LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX without `fontspec` but I can't think why you would wish to.

Comment: For questions like these, a minimal example is usually helpful. Can you please post a small .lyx file showing the problem? Note that a .lyx file is just a text file so it is easy to post.

Answer (score 3):

For the specific case of `fontenc`, go to Document --> Settings --> Fonts, set *LaTeX font encoding* to *Custom*, and type whichever font encoding you wish in the input field.

In general, as in [this answer to a similar question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/141449/lyx-how-to-add-option-to-package-automatically-load), to pass an option to a package you can put it in the document class options. This will pass those options to all packages, so it's dangerous in that if a different package you're loading also takes options with those names (and presumably different meanings!) it will also be passed them.